# Why does Array[T forSome { type T; }] mean Array[Any]

Tags: scala, type-systems, existential-type

I'm reading the article ["Existential types in Scala"](http://www.drmaciver.com/2008/03/existential-types-in-scala/), and found something I can't understand:

```
Array[T] forSome { type T; }
Array[T forSome { type T; }]
```

> They look almost identical, but they're in fact very different. The first is the type of all arrays, whatever their type parameter. The second is Array[Any].

Why are they so different, and especially, why does the second one mean `Array[Any]`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The difference lies in when the type system decides what T is.

Maybe the best answer is, try using those two types in some code, see what happens, and try to figure out why.  But I'll try to explain some type theory first.  In this case:

```
Array[T forSome { type T; }]
```

where the `forSome` is inside the `[]` brackets, each element by itself just has to somehow be explained as `T forSome { type T; }`.  OK, so an `Int` is a `T` for some type `T`, so you can put an `Int` in the array.  A `String` also is a `T` for some type `T`, and because the choice `forSome` applies to only one element at a time, you get to say `T` is `String` this time instead of `Int`, so you can put the `String` in the array even though it already contains an `Int`.

On the other hand, while we can choose `T` independently for any element of the array, the type of the array itself has already been chosen: it is the type of array that can hold anything.  It can't be an `Array[Int]` or an `Array[String]`.

But in this case:

```
Array[T] forSome { type T; }
```

the type `T` is decided just once, outside the array. The array could actually be an `Array[Int]`, and `Array[String]`, or an `Array[Any]`.  But once the type `T` is chosen, all elements of the array have to be consistent with that type.

OK, *now* let's try some code.  Here's an example:

```
scala> var a = Array(1,2);
a: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2)

scala> def first(z : Array[T] forSome { type T }) = z(0);
first: (z: Array[_])Any

scala> def firstany(z : Array[T forSome { type T }]) = z(0);
firstany: (z: Array[T forSome { type T }])Any

scala> first(a);
res0: Any = 1

scala> firstany(a);
error: type mismatch;
 found   : Array[Int]
 required: Array[T forSome { type T }]
       firstany(a);
                ^
```

Why the error?  Because the array `a` has the type `Array[Int]`, which can contain only things of type `Int`.  That's certainly an `Array[T] forSome {type T}`, because all the type system needs to do is choose Int as the type T.  Therefore `first(a)` is OK.  But as explained above, an `Array[T forSome { type T }]` cannot be an `Array[Int]`, so `firstany(a)` is an error.

But the following is OK, because an `Array[Any]` is an `Array[T forSome { type T }]`:

```
scala> var b = Array(1, "x");
b: Array[Any] = Array(1, x)

scala> firstany(b);
res1: Any = 1
```

Answer (score 12):

It should not be surprising that changing the positions of brackets may alter the meaning a lot. A bit like if you switch ∃ and ∀

The first one means : there is some type `T` such that this is an `Array[T]`. So this is satisfied by `Array[String]`, `Array[Int]`, etc. The array is homogenous, but we don't know on which type.

The second one means : for each element of the array, there is some type `T`, such that the element is of type `T`. Which is no constraint at all, so it is just `Array[Any]`. Having the `forSome` inside the square brackets, may be useful if you do e.g.

```
Array[Set[T] forSome {type T}]
```

It means the element of the array are all Sets, but there might be a both a Set of Int and a Set of String in the same array.

---

Regarding Rich Oliver's comment about type erasure: this is mostly a compile time thing, and they are indeed different. In the first case, it is an array whose element type we do not know. So we cannot do e.g `a(0) = 1`, because it might be well be an `Array[String]`. On the opposite, with the second type, it is an `Array[Any]`, and  a(0) = 1 is ok.

Comment: Does not type erasure not rather negate the importance of the distinction in practice? I'm trying to think when it would be actually useful to know the difference in the two types.

Comment: Ah good point, I wasn't thinking mutable. I'll put a second question: does the distinction have any value for immutable collections / immutable generic objects?

Comment: Not sure, but I don't think it would amount to much on a covariant structure (that's why I chose invariant "Set" in my answer). Indeed, existential types are a somewhat late addition to scala, and meant mostly for compatibility which java generic wildcards. Not useful too often with co/contravariance.